# Sortable for has_many does not sort properly

Tags: activeadmin

I have an association of experiences on resume, and create the fields like this:

models/resume.rb

```
has_many :experiences, -> { order(position: :asc) }
```

models/experience.rb

```
belongs_to :resume
acts_as_list scope: :resume
```

Admin page:

```
admin/user.rb
inputs "Experience" do
  f.semantic_fields_for :resume do |r|
    r.has_many :experiences, sortable: :position, allow_destroy: true do |a|
      a.input :title
    end
  end
end
```

When i save the form, the records are not saved in the correct order, nor the reverse of the correct order. On each save, where there are 3 records in my test, the 1st record goes the the bottom, the middle record goes to the top and the last record goes to the middle.

Answer (score 2):

acts_as_list is 1 based, activeadmin defaults to 0 based lists.  adding sortable_start: 1 fixes the issue:

```
inputs "Experience" do
  f.semantic_fields_for :resume do |r|
    r.has_many :educations, sortable: :position, sortable_start: 1, allow_destroy: true do |a|
      a.input :title
    end
  end
end
```